# Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^ne^{t\sqrt{n}}}{n^{3/2}}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the following series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^ne^{t\sqrt{n}}}{n^{3/2}}$$

is convergent, where t is a real parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't $t$ be $<e$?

Comment: It should be...

Answer (score 1):

We have for $0<u<1$,

$$\ln(1-u) = -u + \frac{u^2}2 - \frac{u^3}3 + \ldots \le -u + \frac{u^2}2$$

Then:

$$\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt n}\right)^n = \exp\left(n \ln\left(1 - \frac{e}{\sqrt n}\right) \right) \le \exp\left(n\left(-\frac{e}{\sqrt n} + \frac{n}{2e^2}\right)\right) = \underbrace{e^{e^2/2}}_{:=c} e^{-e \sqrt n}$$

Then the whole term in the sum is bounded above by:

$$\frac{ce^{(t-e)\sqrt n}}{n\sqrt n} \le \frac{c}{n\sqrt n}$$

By comparison test, the series converges.

Comment: When it is divergent?

Comment: When we have t > e.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may use a Taylor series expansion giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^{3/2}}\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^ne^{t\sqrt{n}}&=\frac1{n^{3/2}}e^{\large n\ln\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}e^{t\sqrt{n}}
\\\\&=\frac1{n^{3/2}}e^{\large n\left(-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac1{n}\right)\right)}e^{t\sqrt{n}}
\\\\&=\frac1{n^{3/2}}e^{\large (t-e)\sqrt{n}+O\left(1\right)}
\end{align}
$$ then one sees that the given series is convergent *iff* $t-e<0$.

Comment: When it is divergent?

Comment: @meteomath When $t-e\ge0$.

Comment: And, what happens when t-e>0 ?

Comment: @meteomath We have $t-e>0 \implies t-e\ge0$, isn't it?

Comment: When t-e=0, t=e. Then we have 1/n^3/2. It is a convergent series because this series is Dirichlet's series, 1/n^s, and it  converges , when s>1.

Comment: I think you make a confusion, when $t=e$ we **don't** have $\frac1{n^{3/2}}\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^ne^{e\sqrt{n}}=\frac1{n^{3/2}}$, the precedent equality is *not* true.

Comment: @meteomath You are welcome.